# check pdo php insert success

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
$hpaystmt = $con->_con->prepare(".....");
```

> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(1515) " INSERT INTO hpay ( enccode, orno, hpercode, acctno, amt, curcode, paytype, paycode, entryby, payctr, chrgcode, itemcode, chrgtbl) VALUES ( '000060000000000101783710/14/201722:00:00', '00000000033', '000000001017837', '2017-000165903', '1500', 'PESO', 'F', 'C', '', '1', 'DR', 'DR1', 'MISC') "}====object(PDOStatement)#8 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(1517) " INSERT INTO hpay ( enccode, orno, hpercode, acctno, amt, curcode, paytype, paycode, entryby, payctr, chrgcode, itemcode, chrgtbl) VALUES ( '000060000000000101783710/14/201722:00:00', '00000000033', '000000001017837', '2017-000165903', '100', 'PESO', 'F', 'C', '', '2', 'BIRTC', '085', 'MISC') "}

I get the above code when from

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
var_dump($hpaystmt);
$hpayinsert = $hpaystmt->execute();
echo "==";
echo $hpaystmt->execute() === TRUE ;
echo "==";
```

My aim is to check if the insert is success or not but `echo $hpaystmt->execute() === TRUE ;` this line always return blank that is why i alwats get
`}====` in echo;

I dont get any error from display error and also I wrap this in try catch and I always go in try part not catch.

How can I check this for success insert?

OTHER INFO:

I want to check if success so that if it fails I want to rollback the database my var $hpayinsert is set to $hpayinsert = true; before the inserting. then after i check for true or false then commit or rollback depending on the value of that var.

UPDATE:

after putting `print_r($hpaystmt->errorInfo());` I get:

> Array( [0] => 22001 [1] => 8152 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (SQLExecute[8152] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) [3] => 22001)Array( [0] => 22001 [1] => 8152 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (SQLExecute[8152] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) [3] => 22001)

Comment: try print_r($hpaystmt->errorInfo());

Comment: I think your code works. Can you do echo $hpaystmt->execute() === true ? 'true' : 'false'

Comment: i will update @IuriiDrozdov

Comment: You're doing `execute` twice. You should only do it once. If you need to check the result then store the result or compare it inline. In this case you'd check `$hpayinsert` instead of doing a second execute

Comment: "String or binary data would be truncated." - this is your error message. Check your DB. Make sure your DB fields are big enough to hold the data you are trying to insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You don't need it.

There are three possible scenarios for handling the result of insert operation in PDO:

1. To tell the success, no verification is needed. Just keep with your program flow.
2. To handle an unexpected error, *keep with the same* - no immediate handling code is needed. An exception will be thrown in case of a database error, and it will bubble up to the site-wide error handler that eventually will result in a common 500 error page.
3. To handle an expected error, like a duplicate primary key, **and if you have a certain scenario to handle this very error** - then use a `try..catch` operator.

For a regular PHP user it sounds a bit alien - how's that, not to verify the direct result of the operation? - but this is how *exceptions* work - you check the error somewhere else. Once for all. Extremely convenient.

So, in a generic case you don't need any handling code at all. Just keep your code as is.

I wrote an article on [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) explaining the matter in detail, you may find it useful

**Only in case you have a handling scenario** other than just reporting the error, you could catch an error. To rollback a transaction for example. The code is taken from my [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions):

```
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)");
    foreach (['Joe','Ben'] as $name)
    {
        $stmt->execute([$name]);
    }
    $pdo->commit();
}catch (Exception $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: I want to check if success so that if it fails I want to rollback the database my var `$hpayinsert` is set to `$hpayinsert = true;` before the inserting. then after i check for true or false then commit or rollback depending on the value of that var.. You are saying I dont need that? how can I rollback and commit?

Comment: @Martin you should have stated it in your question. See updated answer.

Comment: @one last question. currently the way i do the checking for rollback I do the if condition. If I do this way any fail in insert will go in catch part? say I have multiple insert statement and I need all of them to be successful then commit?

Comment: @Martin this is exactly how handling transactions with exceptions work. They ARE intended to roll back if one of statements failed.

Comment: my whole way of checking success and fail in database was that way before until now.. happy coding mate :)

Comment: @Martin be sure to check the link I provided. there is a checklist to make sure your transaction would be rolled back on error

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with a try catch

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
var_dump($hpaystmt);
try{
  $hpaystmt->execute();
  echo "It's a success";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

Comment: do not catch an exception only to say that something went wrong